# How do I expand C: drive

Tags: format, raid-0

My C: drive was getting pretty full and wanted to expand it with another SSD. I've tried to setup RAID-0 for the two SSD's. But that didn't really go as plan (don't know what went wrong, but I couldn't get Windows to boot after I 'setup' the RAID 0 configuration.). So I resetted the CMOS and reinstalled Windows in AHCI config on the ADATA SSD (check setup for more information). BUT, something weird happend with the installation apparently when I opened Disk Management, see Image 1.

This is my setup:

- **AsRock Z77 EXTREME4**
- **Intel Core i5 3570K**
- **ADATA S510 Serie 120 GB SSD** (OS is installed here) - SATA3_A0
- **Western Digital WD20EARX 2 TB HDD** (for programs, music, movies etc.) - SATA3_1
- **Windows 7 64-bit**

Added:

- **Samsung 840 EVO 120 GB SSD** - SATA3_A1

Apparently is HHD D: Disk 0, the SSD C: Disk 2 and the new disk Disk 1. PLUS the system seems to be running on the HHD and not the SSD but booting and crashdump are located on the C: drive. But when I look in the HHD the windows folder can't be found there. Only in C: drive. So I don't really get it.

Since I added the new SSD, my boot time went significantly slower (20-30 seconds). Especially the splash screen of BIOS.

[image]
**Image 1**

Alright, so my final question is: How do I fix the problem of windows being installed on both drives (the SSD and HDD) and my main question how do I expand the C: drive to 240 GB with the two SSD's?

Preferences:

- I don't mind formatting disk 1 and 2
- I rather not format disk 0

Comment: You could format the drive with no letter and then use junctions **mklink /j Link Target** to the new drive.  Say your **Documents** was getting big.  Make a folder d:\Documents.  Move the contents to the new folder and **mklink /j c:\users\name\Documents d:\Documents**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly drive F:\ from your picture is the drive you don't want to format and that you also don't want Windows installed on.  I would first fix the data on that drive.  If Windows is truly installed on that drive and you don't want it there I would boot to a Linux live CD and delete the Windows installation from that drive manually.  Now disconnect that drive from the computer.

At this point you should have your 2 SSDs attached to the computer.  Go into your BIOS and enable RAID.  After you have enabled RAID you should look for a message from your RAID controller in the POST messages when booting.  Your motherboard uses an Intel RAID controller so you will need to press `CTRL` + `I` to access the RAID config utility.  This process is described in detail on page 13 of your manual found here:

```
ftp://66.226.78.21/manual/raid/Z77%20Extreme4/English.pdf
```

Alternatively pages 7-12 describe how to configure RAID via the UEFI interface.  In either case add both your SSDs to a RAID 0 array, reboot, then install Windows to the newly created array.  After that is done you can re-attach the HDD you disconnected earlier.

Comment: Thanks for response! I'm not really familiar with Linux OS, but how can I delete windows from that HDD (F:), in the Linux OS? Because there is no "Windows"-folder on that drive, like you would have on your C: drive (if its installed there ofcourse)

Comment: Judging by your picture Windows is not actually installed on that drive.  As you said, there is no Windows folder.  Looks like there are some remnants of a previous Windows install though ($AVG, Boot, Config.Msi, $RECYCLE.BIN, System Volume Information, etc.).  If you are only using that drive to store your data you can safely delete all the files/folders on that drive that you have not intentionally put there.

Comment: OK,in the manual, they say `UEFI Utility > Boot > CSM` (page 8) but there is not option CSM in my BIOS (and my BIOS looks different of the picture, might be an update or something). Same goes for Step 2. I don't have `Intel Rapid Storage`. Only `Intel Rapid Start` and `Intel Smart Connect`

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)